# Metric structure on a group

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, group-theory, sigma-models

I have a question about metric structure on a group manifold $G$. Imagine we have a sigma model, i.e. a map $g: \Sigma\rightarrow G$ from some 2D source to our group. One can define the left/right invariant MC forms $l=g^{-1} {\rm d}g$ and $k={\rm d}gg^{-1}$. One can then introduce a coordinate on the group manifold $\phi^m$ for example and expand the MC forms in the induced coordinates on the lie algebra, getting $l=l^r_m \partial_\mu \phi^m T_r {\rm d}x^\mu$ and
$k=k^r_m \partial_\mu \phi^m T_r {\rm d}x^\mu$, where $\mu=(t,x)$ and $r$ is the lie algebra index.

If one does this it is possible to rewrite the principal chiral model action $S=\int\limits_\Sigma {\rm Tr}(l_\mu l^\mu) {\rm d}x^2$ to a standard sigma model action $S=\int \limits_\Sigma G_{mn}\partial_\mu \phi^m \partial^\mu \phi^n$. Where we have defined a metric $G_{mn}=l^r_m l^s_n \eta_{rs}$, where $\eta_{rs}= {\rm Tr}(T_r T_s)$ is the Killing form. Here actually the coefficient of the MC forms $l^r_m$ serve as vielbeins (tetrads) transferring between group manifold indices and (flat) Lie algebra indices.

My question is about the properties of this metric. Since using the formula $l=g^{-1} {\rm d}g$ the metric can be written using only the group element $g$ and its derivatives. This means that interesting structures like the Riemann tensor, the spin connection, and such can also be written in terms of the group element $g$. I would like to mainly ask where one could find such formulas? Or what to search for? I managed to find only some partial information like that for $G=SU(2)$ the Riemann tensor is just Kronecker deltas and inverse radius squared. But somewhere there must be formulas or theory for a general group, right? For my purposes I am mainly interested in a formula for the spin connection, my guess so far is that I will have $\omega_{m}{}^{rs}=l_m^t f_t{}^{rs}$, although I should be able to calculate this I would like to know some references to where this is studied more properly.

I know perhaps the more familiar structure is just the flat structure induced by the MC form when viewed as a principal bundle connection but that is not what I am interested in.